# How catch onChange event of the month popup on the dijit.Calendar

Tags: dojo, calendar

How catch onChange event of the month popup on the dijit.Calendar.
I didn't found anything on the documentation. 
I use Dojo 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calendar uses an internal widget referenced by `monthWidget`. This widget is calling the  `_onMonthSelect` function in your calendar. I have not found any way to get an event handler to that event (since it's private), but you can of course override the implementation of the widget by doing the following:

```
myCal._onOldMonthSelect = myCal._onMonthSelect;
myCal._onMonthSelect = function(a) {
    myCal._onOldMonthSelect(a); // The old behavior
    alert("Month changed"); // Your wanted behavior
}
```

I made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDHj6/1/) as a proof of concept, but I'm pretty sure this can be improved (by extending the widget for example).

Comment: Then it's not a bad idea to accept this answer, so other people know this question is (correctly) answered.